# Use Component From Shared Module Of A Sub Angular App (nested apps)

Tags: angular, nested, components, shared, subapplication

I have nested Angular Apps:

```
MainApp { 
   projects:{
     App1,
     App2
   }
}
```

I want to use a Component from Sub App (App1), in my (MainApp).
Here is my (MainApp) app.module.ts:

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    App1SharedModule.forRoot(),
    App2SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

I've got Error Message: **'app-xxx' is not a known element:**

Any suggestions ?

Comment: app-xxx is a component from one of the modules..?

Comment: @MikeOne yes it's from my sub application (App1), I want to use <app-xxx> in the parent Application (MainApp), knowing that I imported App1 in MainApp  : imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    App1SharedModule.forRoot(),
    App2SharedModule.forRoot()
  ],

Comment: So are you specifically exporting that components from app1?

Comment: I tried to explicitly export the component in it's module : exports: [xxxComponent]   Then added it to my MainApp module in declarations: [xxxComponent]. I've got this error: The Component 'TestComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.

Comment: I think I should add a SharedModule in the MainApp, and there I can add my reusable components either from my MainApp itself or from my sub-apps